# Openstack "_member_" role and "Member" role

Tags: openstack

Recently, I study Openstack Keystone. When I do

```
keystone role-list
```

I found three roles . They are

```
+----------------------------------+---------------+
|                id                |      name     |
+----------------------------------+---------------+
| cb362e8e96464f9980c232dfd56d2ff5 |     Member    |
| d4218b8761844a70ab4fab54cc3afaf9 | ResellerAdmin |
| 9fe2ff9ee4384b1894a90878d3e92bab |    _member_   |
| 70340c7de4024ffbbbdd15ae9ebbbe83 |     admin     |
+----------------------------------+---------------+
```

I know the "admin role" is the highest role. But I don't know what the differences between "Member" ,"*member*" and "ResellerAdmin". Could someone help me ??Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few references that could answer your question:

ResellerAdmin and admin:
https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack/blob/master/files/keystone_data.sh#L44-L50

_***member*_**:
https://github.com/openstack/keystone/blob/5152f12fc9ff14df0bdff5d7840da81318622c00/etc/keystone.conf.sample#L30-L36

Comment: The ResellerAdmin link is not available anymore :-(

Answer (score 2):

`_ member_` is the default role that is assigned to users when they are created. The other roles listed above seem to be from your devstack instance. Basically, we just have 2 default openstack roles that gets configured: `admin` and `_ member_`. To distinguish `member` and `Member` in your instance, try [https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/4759/member-vs-*member*/](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/4759/member-vs-_member_/) .

Comment: I can't edit the URL (edit queue full). ask.openstack.org was archived, you can find that answer here: https://web.archive.org/web/20210423183014/https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/4759/member-vs-_member_/